# onOptionsItemSelected not called when using actionLayout (SherlockActionBar)

Tags: android

The method onOptionsItemSelected isn't being called when using actionLayout in a menu item.
Am I missing something, or is it a known problem with SherlockActionBar?

Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.article, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   

    Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected()");

    switch (item.getItemId()) {        
        case android.R.id.home:            
            finish();      
            return true; 
        case R.id.menu_item_comment:
            return true;
        default:            
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    
    }
}
```

Menu

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_comment"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar_comment_layout"/>
```

Comment: How does '@layout/action_bar_comment_layout' look like?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

well, you have to set onClickListener on that actionLayout to receive callback. I do it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_more) {
            itemChooser = item.getActionView();
            if (itemChooser != null) {
                itemChooser.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: worked fine, thanks. Btw, you could use findItem instead of iterating through all Menu items

Comment: Can shorten this to:
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu); menu.findItem(R.id.menu_more).getActionView().setOnClickListener(this);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

Comment: You should use MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item) with actionbarcompat.

Comment: You can also do that in onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: Here itemChooser  is a View.

Answer (score 18):

You'll have to add your own `OnClickListener` and explicitly call `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem awesomeMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_awesome);
    View awesomeActionView = awesomeMenuItem.getActionView();
    awesomeActionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onOptionsItemSelected(awesomeMenuItem);
        }
    });
}
```

P.S: Don't know why it doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: best answer, by far

Answer (score 11):

You should use **MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);** instead of **item.getActionView();** if you are developing for older version.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        for (int i = 0; i< menu.size() ;i++) {
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(i);
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.add_item) {
                View view = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
                if (view != null) {
                    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ToDoActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }       
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_require, menu)

    val menuItem = menu!!.findItem(R.id.menu_cart)
    val view = menuItem.actionView
    view.setOnClickListener {
        onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)
    }

    return true
}
```

Working for me (code is in kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    View view = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_comment).getActionView();
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Also, (and that was very important for me, so other answers did not work) you need to disable the clickable option of all views in your action layout (that is, action_bar_comment_layout.xml):

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining @Arun Kumar's and @Luten's answers, the below method will make the implementation generic. For all the menu items using **actionView**, we **setOnClickListener** to call **onOptionsItemSelected(item)**.
This way we can mix and match normal and actionLayout menu items, without worrying about setting individual onClickListeners.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(menuResourceId(), menu);

    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        final MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        View actionView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        if (actionView != null) {
            actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: Very good - thanks a ton!! Sad, that we need such a snipet and the framework does not include it on its own...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues I had to address before fixing this issue. Most relevant to Kotlin as far as I know.

1. Make sure to call this from MainActivities onCreate:

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
```

2.Your Activities onCreate should not implement , persistentState: PersistableBundle?.

So it should look something like this:

```
 class AboutActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding : ActivityAboutBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("AboutActivityLog", "About Activity onCreate called.")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityAboutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

and not like this:

```
class AboutActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding : ActivityAboutBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        Log.d("AboutActivityLog", "About Activity onCreate called.")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        binding = ActivityAboutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```