# How to get/set action event in Android actionbar switch

Tags: android

I found this post [How to add a switch to android action bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107031/how-to-add-a-switch-to-android-action-bar)  and this works for me. But I can't get its event. I'm using appcompat, and I used app namespace for actionLayout and showAsAction, but I'm not able to handle its click on onOptionsItemSelected method?. My app is crashing on start up. how to handle it or what is wrong with this code? 
here is my code

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/myswitch"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"/>
```

switch_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchForActionBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

         MenuItem menuItem= menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch);
         Switch switcha = (Switch)menuItem.findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);
    switcha.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // do anything here on check changed 
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

   if (id == R.id.myswitch) {
       //do something
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post `onOptionsItemSelected` method

Comment: Boss@ actually clicking on switch does not make any fire. Because I don't know how to do it. But I know at least I have to set listener on this switch any way. I need to figure out how to do it. See my edited question for the method

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627892/onoptionsitemselected-not-called-when-using-actionlayout-sherlockactionbar

Comment: Yes Boss. this link helped me find out solution. Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found my error. I have to use

> View view = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);

extra line in onCreateOptionsMenu to find out the switch button 
. Here is my full method

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch);
        View view = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
        Switch switcha = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);
        switcha.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // do anything here on check changed 
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct answer to your question

Comment: thank KeepAlive for responding. It needs 2 days to accept this as correct. I will do it 2 days later

Comment: getActionView is deprecated. and this way dont work for me